# Array of strings and hashes: flatten to make one dimensional

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash

If I have an array that looks like this:

```
['one', { 'two' => 'three' }, 'four']
```

How can I get it to:

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

Things like `.flatten` and `.flat_map` don't remove the inner hashes.

Comment: `['one', { 'two' => 'three' }, 'four'].flat_map { |el| el.is_a?(Hash) ? el.to_a : el }.flatten`

Comment: Not robust, just for fun: `['one', { 'two' => 'three' }, 'four'].to_s.scan(/[a-z]+/)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest solution you are going to get is something on the lines of:

```
['one', { 'two' => 'three' }, 'four'].
  flat_map {|f| f.respond_to?(:flatten) ? f.flatten : f }
```

I prefer the `#respond_to?` as it's generally better to check if it quacks like a duck, not if it is a duck.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it. For example you can just iterate over the array, check if the value is a Hash (if so convert it to array) and then flatten it at the end:

```
array.map!{ |i| i.kind_of?(Hash) ? i.to_a : i }.flatten
```